# Received length differs from sent length

Tags: android, python, httpurlconnection, cherrypy, content-length

I am using an Android app to send a base64 encoded string to a CherryPy server. The Android code works like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://foo.bar/blabla");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(base64s.length());

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write(base64s.getBytes());
```

So, you'd say the amount of bytes sent equals the amount of bytes in the `Content-Length` header. However, in Python, when I run this:

```
cl = cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']
rawbody = cherrypy.request.body.read()

print "{} bytes, {}".format(len(rawbody), cl)
```

The numbers `cl` and `len(rawbody)` are different.

How can that be?

Comment: What are the values??? And how many bytes sent?

Comment: Forgot out.close();?

Comment: @greenapps that was indeed it. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to close the stream with `out.close();` ?

Answer (score 0):

your server sould send a "close header" so the client will no its end stream for him.